# How to apply conditional function based on substring in string in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to append a column to a dataframe with values based on whether or not a string contains contains a specific substring. I will explain here. I am working in python.

I have the following string (or more specifically an object that contains a string):

```
color = "tigerbluetree"
```

Then I have the following dataframe:

```
        Day     Money
-----------------------
0     Day 1         3
1     Day 2         3
2     Day 3         5
3     Day 4         3 
4     Day 5         2
5     Day 6         0
6     Day 7         0
7     Day 8         6 
...
```

Now, I want to create a new column called `Value`. I want the values in `Value` to be a function of whether or not the string `color` contains the substring "blue". If it does contain the substring "blue", which it does in this case, then I want to change all the values in the `Money` column to 0. If it does not contain the substring "blue", then I want to leave all the values in the `Money` column as they are. And so I would want to produce the following dataframe based on the above information:

```
        Day     Money
-----------------------
0     Day 1         0
1     Day 2         0
2     Day 3         0
3     Day 4         0 
4     Day 5         0
5     Day 6         0
6     Day 7         0
7     Day 8         0 
...
```

I have tried to following code:

```
df['Money'] = np.where(color.contains("blue"), 0, df['Money'])
```

and I received the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

How can this be fixed? I am not sure why the `str.contains()` is not working here, as I am working with a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use normal conditional assignment instead of `np.where` since you are not comparing on actual dataframe, instead you are comparing on a separate string:

```py
>>> color = "tigerbluetree"
>>> df['value'] = 0 if 'blue' in color else df['Money']
>>> df

    Day   Money value
0   Day 1   3   0
1   Day 2   3   0
2   Day 3   5   0
3   Day 4   3   0
4   Day 5   2   0
5   Day 6   0   0
6   Day 7   0   0
7   Day 8   6   0
```

Also in the question, you mentioned that you want to create a new column called `value`, but you are trying to overwrite the column `Money`

Answer (score 1):

Strings only have the `__contains__` attribute, or more often we all use the `in` method.

So using `in` instead:

```
df['Money'] = np.where("blue" in color, 0, df['Money'])
```

Then the `df` would look like:

```
     Day  Money            
0    Day 1      0
1    Day 2      0
2    Day 3      0
3    Day 4      0
4    Day 5      0
5    Day 6      0
6    Day 7      0
7    Day 8      0
```